# How to filter multiple columns/rows in a python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Okay so I have a dataframe called `ski_data` that has two columns named `AdultWeekend` and `AdultWeekday` which shows the price for the weekend and weekdays of each ski resort.

However, for some of the resorts, both price columns are NaN and I need to filter that out.

My approach was this:

**Step 1)**

create a new dataframe that takes each ski resort and gives it a value of 0, 1, or 2 based on how many of the price tags are NaN so the code was

```
missing_data = ski_data[['AdultWeekend', 'AdultWeekday']].isnull().sum(axis=1)
```

**Step 2)**

Create a counter variable and an empty list. Then iterate over the missing_data and if the    value == 2. append the counter to the list which keeps track of the index that is equivalent in the ski_data dataframe.

```
counter = 0
missingList = []
for x in missing_price:
    if x==2:
       missingList.append(counter)
    counter += 1
```

**Step 3)**

Iterate over ski_data dataframe and drop location of each index that was appended to the list.

```
for i in missingList:
    ski_data.drop(labels=[i], axis=0, inplace=True)
```

However I get multiple errors one of which involves the first index label that is appended to the missing_list is 98 but ski_data.loc[98] raises a keyError. Can anyone explain or help me?

https://github.com/seungsooim32/stackoverflow/blob/main/02_data_wrangling.ipynb

code task #28

Comment: or, an alternative that requires less manual work, pandas [built-in dropna() function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

Comment: yes ive tried that but its the same error. basically an index label that is not even in the dataframe is included in the list

Comment: dropna() should do the trick. try to provide the function dropna perimiters: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

Comment: or please try to put the example dataframe for us to debug

Comment: https://github.com/seungsooim32/stackoverflow/blob/main/02_data_wrangling.ipynb

Comment: code task #28 is where you shud find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
ski_data.dropna(how="all", subset=['AdultWeekend', 'AdultWeekday'])
```

This will create a new dataframe with NaN rows dropped. If you want to modify the existing dataframe, add the argument `inplace=True`.

Comment: I tried it but it did nothing. the shape is still the same

Comment: I added an explanation.

Comment: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dropna' is the error i get

Comment: Check that your dataframe is still a dataframe and not `None`.

Comment: for the code that you wrote in your example, am I assigning it to a new dataframe variable? so like....... newdf = ski_data.dropna(how="all", subset=['AdultWeekend', 'AdultWeekday'])

Comment: Sure, but check that you did not assign `ski_data` to `None` somewhere along the way.

Comment: Try `ski_data == None`. If the answer is `True`, `ski_data` is not a dataframe anymore.

Comment: Nope its not None

Comment: Ok for some really weird reason it worked now

Answer (score 0):

Don't drop `nan`, keep the right rows:

```
>>> ski_data
   AdultWeekend  AdultWeekday
0          10.0          15.0
1           NaN          12.0
2          13.0           NaN
3          20.0          19.0
4           NaN           NaN

>>> ski_data.loc[ski_data[['AdultWeekend', 'AdultWeekday']].notna().all(axis=1)]
   AdultWeekend  AdultWeekday
0          10.0          15.0
1           NaN          12.0
2          13.0           NaN
3          20.0          19.0

>>> ski_data.loc[~ski_data[['AdultWeekend', 'AdultWeekday']].isna().all(axis=1)]
   AdultWeekend  AdultWeekday
0          10.0          15.0
1           NaN          12.0
2          13.0           NaN
3          20.0          19.0
```

Comment: now im getting an error: NoneType object has no attribute loc

Comment: `df` is an example. Your dataframe name is `ski_data`...

Comment: Can you share a link to `ski_resort_data.csv` please?

Comment: I posted my github